# XML file Parsing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I have a xml file in following format.

```
<Category id="CIBA_VISION" image="Choose_Page\CON_PNG\Ciba_Vision.png">
    <Product id="CON_CIBA_01" image="Buy_Page\Eye_CON_PNG\CIBAVision\List_01.png">
        <Detail image="Buy_Page\Eye_CON_PNG\CIBAVision\Buy_01.png"/>
    </Product>
```

where images contains image path in specified folder which is in resource folder of project.

My question is: After parsing this xml file, will the image tag pick the values from the folder or it will show only path after parsing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried parsing this XML. Are you able to trace the imagePath that you mentioned in the XML? If you get the image, the way suggested by Jenifer will get you the image.

Comment: No i have not. But i want to know this xml file format is possible to parse or not as we do in web services parsing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *imaegeString = @"Ciba_Vision.png";
NSArray *pathComponents = [imaegeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
NSString *imageName=[pathComponents lastObject];
UIImage *img8 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName]];
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

It will only contain the values you see there, except you add the base to URLs while parsing yourself.

And picking completely depends on your context, how do you like the code to pick?

Comment: Neither do I get you then. What do you mean by "After parsing this xml file, will the image tag pick the values from the folder or it will show only path after parsing." and please provide some code on how you parse the file.

Comment: Actually i m trying to parse this file as i parse web services. Can it possible ?

Comment: Actually i m new in iPhone. So don't understand how to parse this xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

you ll get only path after parsing it wont do anything with that path.we have use that path and do our work thats it

some sample is

```
  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString: @"Detail"]){
       //get all the attributes of from the dictionary(attributeDict)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get the image by the following code in your imageView You can try this:-

```
 NSString *imaegeString = @"Choose_Page\CON_PNG\Ciba_Vision.png";
    NSArray *pathComponents = [imaegeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
    NSString *imageName=[pathComponents lastObject];
    UIImage *img8 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName]];
```

Hope this might help you...If this work you can do same for another strings in your parsing...